# System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException with Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: c#, generics, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am using the Microsoft Bot Framework to create a really simple bot using a LuisDialog. However I keep getting a System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException.

Here's my controller:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
{
    if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
    {
        await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new QuotesDialog());
    }
    else
    {
        HandleSystemMessage(activity);
    }
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    return response;
}
```

Here's my dialog:

```
[Serializable]
[LuisModel("MyModelIdGoesHere", "MySubscriptionKeyGoesHere")]
public class QuotesDialog : LuisDialog<object>
{
    [LuisIntent("CheckQuote")]
    public async Task CheckQuote(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        await context.PostAsync("Hello you!");
        context.Wait(MessageReceived);
    }

    [LuisIntent("None")]
    public async Task None(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        await context.PostAsync("I'm sorry. I didn't get that.");
        context.Wait(MessageReceived);
    }
}
```

If I use an older version of the Bot Framework, like 3.0.0, I get the following error:
500 InternalServerError
{
    "message": "An error has occurred."
}

However if I update to the latest stable version (3.2.1) then I get the following error of the type "System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException":

> "Exception: System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given
>   key was not present in the dictionary. at
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2.get_Item(TKey key) at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.LuisDialog "

The full stack trace is here:

http://pastebin.com/uLJF5fcV

I tried create a new project on another solution, but I get the same error. I tried install different versions of the Bot Framework via nuget but like I said previously, one way or another I still get an error. I have really little experience with the Bot Framework so far, so I don't really know what else to try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try again adding the following on top of the None method?

```
[LuisIntent("")]
```

The error that you are seeing is usually happening when the LuisDialog cannot resolve the method (intent) to execute based on the message received.

I suspect the issue is being raised [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/5cf71c742f27d89e9dbc4076f850122bd6edac11/CSharp/Library/Dialogs/LuisDialog.cs#L203), when the LuisDialog looks for the empty intent.

```
handler = this.handlerByIntent[string.Empty];
```

Comment: That's exactly right, and also needs to be reflected in the docs.